# Java generics and reflection to create and set model for SimpleJdbcCall in Spring

Tags: java, spring, generics, jdbc, reflection

I am trying to use reflection and generics to create models using `SimpleJdbcCall`. At the moment I have to create a distinct mapper per model that I add to the project. I would like to create a mapper that uses reflection to just simply map the model, so that I only have to write one mapper (in the method below).

Here is my implementation so far:

```
@Repository
public abstract class DAO<T extends ModelBase> {

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    DAO(final DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    protected List<T> buildModels(SqlParameterSource sqlSource, Class modelBase) {
        final String RESULT_SET = "RESULT_SET";
        return (List<T>)new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
            .withCatalogName("someCatalog")
            .withSchemaName("someSchema")
            .withProcedureName(getProcForModel(modelBase))
            .returningResultSet(RESULT_SET, (ResultSet rs, int rowNum) -> {
                /*
                1. get an actual instance of the modelBase reference that is passed in
                2. get references to the setters of the modelBase instance
                   or be able to pick out where to set things in the constructor of the modelBase
                3. loop thru ResultSet, setting parameters on model where the name of the
                   setter or constructor arg matches the name of the column in the resultSet
                */
            }).execute(sqlSource).get(RESULT_SET);
    }

}
```

The `modelBase` class referenced passed in would obviously be a class that inherits from the abstract `ModelBase` class.

The issues I have enumerated above are the things that I have not been able to figure out how I am supposed to do using the Reflection API in Java. Does anyone know how to do what I am trying to achieve?

Also, some of the values coming from the `resultSet` might not be `Strings`, but rather things like `Dates` and `boolean`. How would I reflectively call the right method on the `resultSet`? i.e. `getInts()` or `getDate()` or `getBoolean()`, etc.

Comment: Should you keep a `final` reference to the `DataSource` like that?  You can't release that resource that way, and I'd guess that a DataSource is a pretty heavy weight object.  I am *guessing* but I think connection pooling might be a better idea here.

Comment: @markspace I am not familiar with the issue you are describing. Do you have any reading material on the topic of why 'final' doesnt release the resource? As for connection pooling, I will have to ask, but I was under the impression that Tomcat was handling the pools... Moreover, I thought Spring was simply creating a singleton instance of the DataSource anyway.

Comment: Notice here in this example they null the data source out after they're done, to release the resource: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html I'm not an expert so I don't know if this is current best practice, but I would ask before I made a DataSource `final` like that.